# tiptap font size react

Tags: reactjs, font-size, tiptap

I'm using tiptap as an editor in my react application,
the problem is that I haven't found how to modify the font size inside my editor, I have searched for an external package but I have not found any.
could someone tell me is there is a package for font-size for tiptap with react ?

Comment: Does this extension help you? https://tiptap.dev/api/marks/text-style

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To handle font size in tiptap, you can create custom extension eg:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import { Extension } from '@tiptap/react';

/**
 * FontSize - Custom Extension
 * editor.commands.setFontSize(e.target.value) :set the font-size.
 */


 export const FontSize = Extension.create({
    name: 'fontSize',
    addOptions() {
        return {
            types: ['textStyle'],
        };
    },
    addGlobalAttributes() {
        return [
            {
                types: this.options.types,
                attributes: {
                    fontSize: {
                        default: null,
                        parseHTML: element => element.style.fontSize.replace(/['"]+/g, ''),
                        renderHTML: attributes => {
                            if (!attributes.fontSize) {
                                return {};
                            }
                            return {
                                style: `font-size: ${attributes.fontSize}`,
                            };
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        ];
    },
    addCommands() {
        return {
            setFontSize: fontSize => ({ chain }) => {
                return chain()
                    .setMark('textStyle', { fontSize: fontSize + "px" })
                    .run();
            },
            unsetFontSize: () => ({ chain }) => {
                return chain()
                    .setMark('textStyle', { fontSize: null })
                    .removeEmptyTextStyle()
                    .run();
            },
        };
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to extend the textStyle extension and use the addAttributes method rather than create a new extension. addOptions is also not useful here and does not make sense

Answer (score 4):

I think the most appropriate solution is to extend the TextStyle extension as below :

```
import TextStyle from '@tiptap/extension-text-style';

declare module '@tiptap/core' {
    interface Commands<ReturnType> {
        fontSize: {
            /**
             * Set the font size
             */
            setFontSize: (size: string) => ReturnType;
            /**
             * Unset the font size
             */
            unsetFontSize: () => ReturnType;
        };
    }
}

export const TextStyleExtended = TextStyle.extend({
    addAttributes() {
        return {
            ...this.parent?.(),
            fontSize: {
                default: null,
                parseHTML: (element) => element.style.fontSize.replace('px', ''),
                renderHTML: (attributes) => {
                    if (!attributes['fontSize']) {
                        return {};
                    }
                    return {
                        style: `font-size: ${attributes['fontSize']}px`
                    };
                }
            }
        };
    },

    addCommands() {
        return {
            ...this.parent?.(),
            setFontSize:
                (fontSize) =>
                ({ commands }) => {
                    return commands.setMark(this.name, { fontSize: fontSize });
                },
            unsetFontSize:
                () =>
                ({ chain }) => {
                    return chain()
                        .setMark(this.name, { fontSize: null })
                        .removeEmptyTextStyle()
                        .run();
                }
        };
    }
});
```

And after you can use it :

```
editor.commands.setFontSize(14);
editor.commands.unsetFontSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the answer by @Raed BAHRI results in TypeScript errors. To fix, you need to extend the Commands interface as below:

```
import { Extension } from '@tiptap/react';

/**
 * FontSize - Custom Extension
 * editor.commands.setFontSize(e.target.value) :set the font-size.
 */

// --------- add this block ---- vvvvvv ----------
declare module '@tiptap/core' {
  interface Commands<ReturnType> {
    fontSize: {
      /**
       * Set the font size
       */
      setFontSize: (size: string) => ReturnType;
      /**
       * Unset the font size
       */
      unsetFontSize: () => ReturnType;
    };
  }
}
// ---------------- add this block ----- ^^^^ --------------

 export const FontSize = Extension.create({
    name: 'fontSize',
    addOptions() {
        return {
            types: ['textStyle'],
        };
    },
    addGlobalAttributes() {
        return [
            {
                types: this.options.types,
                attributes: {
                    fontSize: {
                        default: null,
                        parseHTML: element => element.style.fontSize.replace(/['"]+/g, ''),
                        renderHTML: attributes => {
                            if (!attributes.fontSize) {
                                return {};
                            }
                            return {
                                style: `font-size: ${attributes.fontSize}`,
                            };
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        ];
    },
    addCommands() {
        return {
            setFontSize: fontSize => ({ chain }) => {
                return chain()
                    .setMark('textStyle', { fontSize: fontSize + "px" })
                    .run();
            },
            unsetFontSize: () => ({ chain }) => {
                return chain()
                    .setMark('textStyle', { fontSize: null })
                    .removeEmptyTextStyle()
                    .run();
            },
        };
    },
});
```

Answer (score -3):

the answer for how to handle font size in tiptap is to use setMark from the "@tiptap/extension-text-style" extension.
e.g :

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          editor
            .chain()
            .focus()
            .setMark("textStyle", {
              fontSize: "100px"
            })
            .run();
        }}
      >
```